# C#;setting key and values in dictionary with tuple of strings

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization, tuples

I'm pretty new to C#, so please direct accordingly.  I have this declaration:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
```

I want to set the key and field of the Tuple as:

```
myDictionary.Add( myKey, Tuple<firstValue, secondValue> );
```

where firstValue and secondValue are strings that will be keys to another dictionary.  I would like some help on the syntax for the initialization of the Tuple in the .Add() method.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

myDictionary.Add(myKey, new Tuple<string, string>(firstValue, secondValue));
```

You need to call the constructor of Tuple.

Comment: Tuple.Create() is usually a bit easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

myDictionary.Add("key", new Tuple<string, string>("firstValue", "secondValue"));
```

Comment: Thanks to M. Pillapan.  Just what I needed.  And for reference, I was missing the concept of declaring the `Tuple` as `code` in the `Add` method.